# Force application to close fd or cause EIO (linux)

Tags: linux, file-io

Due to stupid design  certain application do not track pids of created processes. There is a bug (CVE level!) when created process (scp) continue to read deleted file.

Is any way to force all applications, accessing specific file to close fd or get EIO on read operations?

There is ugly trick with fuser -k /path/to/file, but it is too ugly and too broad (not all accessing applications should be closed, but only received IO error).

I've tried:

- Truncate (scp continue to work)
- Setting mandatory locks on the file or parts of the files (they are only advisory until fs is not mounted with 'mand' option)
- Reopen file with all strange combination of open flags
- Play with access rights to file (does not affect already opened files)

I understand that proper way is just to record pid of scp and kill -9 it. But this is CVE fix to the big project and execution code is shared between thousands of pieces and any change to it in the 'stable/support' part of lifecycle (where fix is intended) will be rejected.

Any ideas? If no, there going to be 'fuser -k /path/to/file'.

Comment: This is not a bug. It's the way Linux (and quite a few other Unix-likes) were designed to work. The file is not truly deleted (freeing up storage, etc.) until the last process that has the file open closes that file descriptor. The directory entry may be removed, preventing additional processes from starting to use the file, but the file is still there until everything has stopped using it. If you don't want those semantics, you'll have to write your own OS that has different semantics...

Comment: I know. I just asked if there is a way to change file (attributes, exclusive locks, fctrls, ioctl, etc) to cause error in the read operation for open file in other application.